# error while trying to build a chart in lWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to build a chart LWC using Chartjs javascript libraries. 
I keep getting error when I try to build the chart:

> C is not a function

Below is my component Js :

```
Import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';

import Chart from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Chart';

import ChartData from '@salesforce/apex/GraphController.getChartMap';

import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TrkChart extends LightningElement {

    @track brachartname = 'barchart';
    @track chartData;
    @track dispmsg = 'testing';
    @track Chartinti = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if(this.chartinti){
            return;
        }
        this.chartinti = true;
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, Chart + '/Chart/Chart.bundle.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, Chart + '/Chart/Chart.min.css')

        ])
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispmsg = this.dispmsg + 'err1: '+ error.message ;

        });
    }

    @wire(ChartData) chartDet(result){
        if(result.data){
            this.chartData = [];
            this.chartData = result.data;
            this.createGraph();
        } else if (result.error){
          this.charterr = 'Unable to load chart data'+ result.error;
          this.dispmsg = this.charterr;
        }
    }


    createGraph(){        
        var dataMap = [];
        var ctx = [];
        ctx =this.template.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d'); 
        dataMap= {"chartLabels": Object.keys(this.chartData),
        "chartData": Object.values(this.chartData)
        };

        try{
            Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: dataMap.chartLabels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'My Data',
                        data: dataMap.chartData,
                        backgroundColor: ['rgba(153,255,51,0.4)']
                    }]
                },
                options: {  
                    scales: {  
                      yAxes: [{  
                        ticks: {  
                          beginAtZero:true 
                        }  
                      }]  
                    }  
                  }   
            }); 
        }catch(err){
            this.dispmsg = this.dispmsg+ ' error '+err.message; --> error caught here
        }
    }

}
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Here is my template

```
<template> 
<div>
        <canvas class='bar' lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>   
</div>  
<div>{dispmsg}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: is there a line number associated with the error? if not, is it being thrown from the chartjs library itself?

Comment: I was thinking It is from the Chartjs library. Having said that the above template gives the error 'B is not a function' , if I add a chart div code block in a lighting card I get the error 'C is not a function'.

Comment: looks like you willll have to debug to find out what is causing this =/

Answer (score 2):

I received the error "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1" with the answers here and found that the LWC Recipes libChartjs control is the best starting point for a couple of reasons.  (libsChartjs code is here: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsChartjs)

After searching a bit, I found out that the latest Chartjs (2.9.3) is not compatible with the LWC locker service.  So, the most important note is to use the **2.7.3** version of Chartjs as your static resource.

You can simply install LWC Recipes in your org and you will have a working Chartjs chart ready to go.  Installation steps are in the readme: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes.  You will also have a v2.7.3 chart.js file in your static resources.

Comment: I think the reason the LWC recipe example works is because it creates the canvas within JS rather than most of the examples online put this in the .html file. They have updated the static resource to 2.9.3 and it works just fine.

Comment: in my case, as you mentioned the version was the problem, I had to use the 2.7.3 version instead of the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried loading chart js with the sample data on line chart.You can use this as starting point.
[image]

**HTML**

```
<template>
<div>
    <canvas class="line-chart" width="800" height="450" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Component JS**

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import chart from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chart';


 export default class Chartcmp extends LightningElement {
  @api chartjsInitialized = false;
   @api recordId;
   renderedCallback() {
        if (this.chartjsInitialized) {
          return;
         }
        this.chartjsInitialized = true;
        console.log('chartjs loading');
        Promise.all([
              loadScript(this, chart + '/chart/Chart.min.js')
        ])
    .then(() => {
        this.Initializechartjs();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error loading chartJs',
                message: error.message,
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
    });
   }

  Initializechartjs() {
    console.log("loaded");
    //Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var ctx = this.template.querySelector(".line-chart");
    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx ,{
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label:'Day',
                    data: [110, 290, 150, 250, 500, 420, 100],
                    borderColor:'rgba(62, 159, 222, 1)',
                    fill: false,
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    pointBorderWidth: 4,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    bezierCurve: true,
                    pointHitRadius: 10
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {  
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                padding: 10,
            },
            responsive: true
        }
       });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that helped

Comment: I am getting Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' error. can anyone helpe

Comment: @manishporwal, if you didn't manage to figure this out, check sfsf610's solution

Answer (score 0):

After Getting some help here Below changes got the code working 
1) Used Chart.min Js files instead of Chart.bundle.min files in static resources.
2) Added 'responsive: true' attribute.
3) tweaked the template element to Have width and Height.

````
<template> 
        <div class = 'slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background' >
                <canvas class="barChart"  width="800" height="450" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>  
        </div> 
</template>

```JS
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import chartJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Chart';
import ChartData from '@salesforce/apex/GraphController.getChartMap';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TrkChart extends LightningElement {
    @track brachartname = 'barchart';
    @track chartData = [];
    @track dispmsg = 'testing';
    @track chartinti = false;
    @wire(ChartData) chartDet(result){
        if(result.data){
            this.chartData = result.data; 
            this.dispmsg = this.dispmsg + 'Got Data'  ;
                this.createGraph();
        } else if (result.error){
          this.charterr = 'Unable to load chart data'+ result.error;
          this.dispmsg = this.dispmsg+ this.charterr;
        }
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        if(this.chartinti){
            return;
        }

        this.chartinti = true;
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, chartJS + '/Chart.min.js')
        ]).then(()=>{
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispmsg = this.dispmsg + 'err1: '+ error.message ;
        });
    }    

    createGraph(){        
        var dataMap = [] ;
        var ctx =[];
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        var barChart;
        dataMap={"chartLabels": Object.keys(this.chartData),
        "chartData": Object.values(this.chartData)
        };
        ctx = this.template.querySelector(".barChart");
    try{
        // eslint-disable-next-line 
        barChart = new Chart(ctx,{
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: dataMap.chartLabels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Usage statistics',
                        data: dataMap.chartData,
                        backgroundColor: ['rgba(153,255,51,0.4)']
                    }]
                },
                options: {  
                    scales: {  
                      yAxes: [{  
                        ticks: {  
                          beginAtZero:true 
                        }  
                      }]  
                    },  
                    responsive: true
                  }   
            }) ;
    }catch(err){
        this.dispmsg = this.dispmsg + err;
    }
    }
}

``` Css
THIS .custom-background {
    background-color: white;
}
````

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answer for the benefit of others.